# Mysqli transaction query over normal php mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

I'm trying to use a mysql transaction query over php mysqli query like this:

```
$sql = "START TRANSACTION; 
        INSERT INTO songs (title, disco, deleted) VALUES ('".$titol."', '".$codi."', '0'); 
        SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
        INSERT INTO lyrics (`lyricsOri`, `lyricsTra`, `song`, `deleted`) VALUES ('".$lyricsO."', '".$lyricsT."', @last_id, 0);  
        COMMIT;";
connection()->query($sql);
```

If I get the `$sql` value after it and copy-paste as sql command into php my admin, it runs nice and it does what it's supposed to do but, when I run this through php it does not work and I can't figure out why.

I know I could use php native transaction, setting it auto_commit(FALSE) and adding the different queries on it to finaly commit it, but in this case I would like to use a mysql command "as is" and I can't find why it's not working properly.

Anyone see the fault or can tell me why it does not work?

Thanks!

Comment: By default PHP mysql's clients does not support multiple SQL statements separated with semicon `;`. So you need to use multiple query calls. Besides you should also read about preventing SQL injections https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried using [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @raymond-nijland pointed out, PHP client does not support multiple SQL statements separated with semicolon.

But this is half-true.
You can use multi_query:

```
$sql = "START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO songs (title, disco, deleted) VALUES ('".$titol."', '".$codi."', '0'); SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO lyrics (`lyricsOri`, `lyricsTra`, `song`, `deleted`) VALUES ('".$lyricsO."', '".$lyricsT."', @last_id, 0); COMMIT;";

connection()->multi_query($sql);
```

Or, as you wrote, using a php transaction, which will takes you to the same result:

```
    connection()->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);
    connection()->query("START TRANSACTION;");
    connection()->query("INSERT INTO songs (title, disco, deleted) VALUES ('".$titol."', '".$codi."', '0');");
    connection()->query("SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();");
    connection()->query("INSERT INTO lyrics (`lyricsOri`, `lyricsTra`, `song`, `deleted`) VALUES ('".$lyricsO."', '".$lyricsT."', @last_id, 0);");
    connection()->query("COMMIT;");
    connection()->commit();
    connection()->close();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, let me take a try on it! :)

Comment: It worked like charm, thanks a lot!